# Migrating from Desktop PC to real Server

Tags: ubuntu, migration

i am a student, working as a part-time Administrator at a startup. I never ever used a real Server ( only a Desktop Pc with apache )
The Company i am working for is growing and they want to switch to a real Server.
My idea would be to use the Ubuntu build-in Backup function and use this Backup file as Base for the Rack-Server, but i don't know, which problems i would run into. Is it a good idea ?

So basically my question is :
**What is the easiest way to migrate from a Desktop PC to a real Rack-Server? ( on an Ubuntu Server) **

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be possible to boot the Server with an live cd and rsync the old server's hard disk contents to the new server. But since it is only a Web server, it would be easier to only copy the configuration files and the webroot.

This means copying the contents of /etc/apache and /var/www to the new server; and creating a MySQL(?) dump, to transfer the databases you might have used.

Comment: Agreed - using rsync proficiently (and then fixing the boot loader) makes sure you know what has been transferred exactly - make sure clocks somewhat agree when using rsync without the -c option. Since a "real" rack server that nonredundantly serves a site should IMAO contain a proper RAID controller and at least two disks (if you have two, RAID1 is the choice NEVER RAID0 unless you know the difference!), you might need to modify your list of kernel modules to load (and update initrd or manually fix it!)